# How to connect php and mysql using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I had created a simple file to test the connection of **php** and **mysql**.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("port", "root", "123456", "mysql");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "</br>";

    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "</br>";

    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL. "\n";
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL. "\n";

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

At first line, I have to write down real port number instand of "port", but I don't know what my port number is.

My **docker-compse.yml** is like following:

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "3002:80"
        volumes:
            - "./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d"
            - "./workshop:/workshop"
        networks:
            - app_net
        container_name: "compose-nginx"
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./php-mysqli/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - "./workshop:/workshop"
        networks:
            - app_net
        container_name: "compose-php"
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
        networks:
            app_net:
                ipv4_address: 10.10.10.1
        container_name: "compose-mysql"
networks:
    app_net:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 10.10.0.0/16
```

Seems like I almost done, I already connect nginx and php.

But I don't know how to connect php and mysql, can any help me solve this problem?

Comment: The first argument needs to be the hostname of your DB server, which in docker-compose is the service name. So you need `mysqli_connect('mysql',...)`. The port is argument 5, but the default of 3306 should work.

Comment: @TobiasK. Container name(mysql) works for me, thanks man! But what is default of 3306? Did you mean "mysql:3306"?

Comment: In your question you said you didn't know what to put in for "port", but the port should not be passed there. See the [docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php#refsect1-mysqli.construct-parameters), the port is a seperate argument, `mysql:3306` thus is likely wrong. And 3306 is the default more MySQL so you do not need to pass that argument. I added the solution as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of `mysqli_connect` needs to be the **hostname** of your DB server (not port), which in docker-compose is the service name. So you need:

```php
mysqli_connect('mysql', ...)
```

---

According to [the docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php#refsect1-mysqli.construct-parameters) the port is argument 5. It defaults to 3306 so you do not need to pass it.